# How to use prezto with zsh on cyginw

Tags: cygwin, zsh

I have setup perzto with zsh on cygwin. 
I am using the default sorin theme as my prompt. I see 3 rectangles as the end of my prompt instead of 3 ">>>". Is there a way to fix it? Can I use a different font to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use different font. In the [Readme of his dotfiles](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/dotfiles) the author of prezto mentions Monaco font. You may get one from [here](https://github.com/todylu/monaco.ttf)